# Create shared to do list folder in MS office 2013 and assign to team members

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have been able to figure out the basics of the question that I want to ask but need more clarification on how it will work in real time and what do I need to do in order to make sure that this solution works.

The situation is:

I am working on a lot of projects all together for which I need to regularly update my team as well as assign responsibility to people for particular task. My  intention was to create a list of projects as To Do list and keep updating the notes till the end of project. In between I need to assign tasks to team members. This gives them a snapshot visibility of where each project is upto and they can open the task and go through notes to get what all steps have been completed.

The method that I have adopted is as following:

In my MS Outlook 2013 in the task menu I have created a new folder named Project. Intention is to give access to my entire team for them to view.

I am creating individual tasks for each project and updating them with notes.

I want to understand the following:

1. If I assign a particular task to a team member who has access to the folder, will it disappear from every ones shared folder or will still be visible in the same folder?
2. In notes section, I want the outlook to automatically pick up the initials of the person typing (Similar to what happens in the comments of a message reply) but can't find any place to do so. Is this possible?
3. After assigning the task will do I have a method to send reminder with in the task to the team member or I still need to manually follow it up?
4. How can I get the team member to send the task back to me once they have updated notes?
5. Can I restrict team members from editing anything in the task apart from notes (Like they can't mark it as complete or change the subject or change the due date)

I know there might be some software and share point available to do this kind of thing but the use is very limited hence no sense in investing into them and also outlook  is used by every one hence it will give a quick overview instead of logging into something new.

Comment: This is a very broad question. It seems to me you can answer most of it yourself by trying things out (with one of your teams members to help to test) and seeing if they work or not.

Comment: I'm afraid that Outlook on it's own is not really going to help here. If you are using Office, you should have access to OneNote and that is much better for what you want. Simply create a notebook on a shared drive, SharePoint, Dropbox or whatever where everyone can get to it. Everyone can edit notes and their initials will appear beside the paragraphs they edit. You can do simple todo lists and even sync the lists to outlook tasks. If you want more, you need to be using a full collaboration platform such as SharePoint, you might try Office 365 for that.